# Passport - "Unauthenticated." - Laravel 5.3

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.3, laravel-passport

I hope someone could explain why I'm `unauthenticated` when already has performed a successfull `Oauth 2` authentication process.

I've set up the `Passport` package like in Laravel's documentation and I successfully get authenticated, receives a token value and so on. But, when I try to do a `get` request on, let say, `/api/user`, I get a `Unauthenticated` error as a response. I use the token value as a header with key name `Authorization`, just as described in the docs.

```
Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
})->middleware("auth:api");
```

This function is suppose to give back my self as the authenticated user, but I'm only getting `Unauthenticated`. Likewise, if I just return the first user, I'm again getting `Unauthenticated`.

```
Route::get('/test', function(Request $request) {
    return App\User::whereId(1)->first();
})->middleware("auth:api");
```

In a tutorial from `Laracast`, guiding through the setup of `Passport`, the guider **doesn't** have the `->middleware("auth:api")` in his routes. But if its not there, well then there's no need for authentication at all!

Please, any suggestions or answers are more then welcome!

Comment: Maybe you could check if you are sending "Bearer <access_token>" in Authorization Header

Comment: Im not even getting "Unauthenticated" I get immediately redirected to the login page.

Comment: All the `routes` that you write inside your `routes\api.php` file are by **default** protected with the **api middleware**. So, you can remove your explicit mentioning of `->middleware("auth:api")` .

Comment: In addition with @Urizev comment, can you also check that your token is not expired and/or revoked just in case. Your route translates to yourapproute/user , so make sure you are requesting to this route instead of yourapproute/api/user . Verify this using php artisan route:list that your route is guarded by auth:api

Answer (score 5):

You have to set an expiration date for the tokens you are generating,

set the boot method in your AuthServiceProvider to something like the code below and try generating a new token. Passports default expiration returns a negative number

```
public function boot()
{
  $this->registerPolicies();
   Passport::routes();
   Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(15));
   Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(30));
}
```

Comment: `By default, Passport issues long-lived access tokens that never need to be refreshed.` - https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#configuration

Answer (score 2):

Check your user model and the database table, if you have modified the primary id field name to say something other than "id" or even "user_id" you MIGHT run into issues. I debugged an issue regarding modifying the primary id field in my user model and database table to say "acct_id" instead of keeping it as just "id" and the result was "Unauthenticated" When I tried to get the user object via GET /user through the auth:api middleware. Keep in mind I had tried every other fix under the sun until I decided to debug it myself.

**ALSO Be sure to UPDATE your passport. As it has had some changes made to it in recent weeks.**

I'll link my reference below, it's VERY detailed and well defined as to what I did and how I got to the solution.

Enjoy!

https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/151

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error because I forgot to put http before the project name.

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/', function () {
    $query = http_build_query([
        'client_id' => 3,
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://consumer.dev/callback',
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'scope' => '',
    ]);

    // The redirect URL should start with http://
    return redirect('passport.dev/oauth/authorize?'.$query);
});

Route::get('/callback', function (Request $request) {
    $http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

    $response = $http->post('http://passport.dev/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'client_id' => 3,
            'client_secret' => 'M8y4u77AFmHyYp4clJrYTWdkbua1ftPEUbciW8aq',
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://consumer.dev/callback',
            'code' => $request->code,
        ],
    ]);

    return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error because of that I deleted passport mysql tables(`php artisan migrate:fresh`), `php artisan passport:install` helps me. Remember that after removing  tables, you need to re-install passport!