# Laravel 5.4 passport axios always returns Unauthenticated

Tags: laravel, jwt, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

I've followed the guide here:https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript

Using axios:

```
...
mounted: function() {

            axios.get('/api/user')
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response)
                })
                .catch(function (response) {
                    console.error(response);
                });
        },
```

But the response is always unauthenticated, I check to see if a laravel_token cookie is present and it is:

[image]

I'm running on apache2 ( docker )

---- Update --

Upon debugging, its actually the xsrf token thats failing in this method in `TokenGuard`:

```
/**
     * Authenticate the incoming request via the token cookie.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function authenticateViaCookie($request)
    {

        try {
            $token = $this->decodeJwtTokenCookie($request);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return;
        }

        # This is not passing:
        if (! $this->validCsrf($token, $request) ||
            time() >= $token['expiry']) {
            return;
        }


        if ($user = $this->provider->retrieveById($token['sub'])) {
            return $user->withAccessToken(new TransientToken);
        }
    }
```

I have the appropriate setup in boostrap.js :

```
window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
};
```

Comment: I had a similar question. See if you might find an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39228194/passport-unauthenticated-laravel-5-3

Comment: @RikardOlsson updated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is actually a Laravel / documentation issue.

The passport token guard is looking for `X-CSRF-TOKEN`, but axios sends `X-XSRF-TOKEN`. Change your axios configuration to:

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.Laravel.csrfToken,
  'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
};
```

I've opened an [PR](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/4128) and this should be default in future Laravel versions.

Comment: Where is window.Laravel.csrfToken?

Comment: @user3098538 it should be in your /resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php view, inside the head tag.