# Consume Your own API - Unauthorized

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I've done some googling and checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42030727/laravel-5-4-passport-axios-always-returns-unauthenticated)) but am still facing a 401 Unauthorized response when consuming my own api from my laravel app from a non logged in user.

I've followed the official docs and have installed passport.

I've also have this on every axios request:

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

Token is also defined on my boilerplate:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Why are the requests still unauthorised?

Comment: I would honestly give Postman a try to figure out why you cannot consume your api.

It is seriously one of the best tools I have stumbled upon.

Comment: Hmm seems like I have to be a logged in user, all works when I log in - how can my API be consumed by non logged in users, ie. get all news posts?

Comment: based on your comment I am suspicious that your request its ending up on web routes instead of api routes! Do you set axios headers `Accept:application/json` and `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: and add the endpoint(axios and backend) that you are trying to reach as well as controller method.

Comment: The endpoint is there, how can I set the axios header like that?

Comment: I have just checked and it's set as Content-Type: application/json and  Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*

Comment: Your code seems ok. Just to be sure, is the `VerifyCsrfToken` who is handling this? Can't you disable this middleware just to be sure that this is the problem? Just comment the line for `VerifyCsrfToken` in `Http/Kernel.php` and test again.

Comment: There is no verify crsf token on api routes so it would not be that.

Answer (score 1):

If your api route is wrapped in the `auth:api` middleware, the key word being auth, then what you're doing will be impossible unless your user is not first logged in.

You can remove the auth and just have the `api` middleware but this will not protect this endpoint from cross-site/unauthorised requests.

A solution could be to create a [client credentials grant token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#client-credentials-grant-tokens) and send it through to your front-end, although you'll have to store this somewhere.

Personally because it's your own api I'd just create a route or route group in its own file and `require` this file into both your `web` and `api` route files. Therefore you'll be able to consume it from your own web app with the csrf protection & if you try to access it elsewhere it will need the prepended `api` in the url `https://website.com/api` and an access token.

Comment: you have made a big point there @Luke Vincent, with "auth" middleware  that first needs a logged in . user before even goin to the 'api' check. i suggest auth:api should be removed from the Http/Kernel.php file under the api array, the being added only to the route/api.php file to the routes that need authenticated user

Answer (score 0):

Okay then, do not use "auth:api" for routes that do not  need authenticated users, Why then?,  have you noticed the key word AUTH === authenticated on 'auth:api" middleware ?  this means it requires an authenticated user or rather check for authentication first even before going to api check.

So what to do ?

If you happen to have made that every request should got under "auth:api" middleware check under Http/Kernel.php file like below

```
'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
        'auth:api'
    ],
```

Just remove it there and add this middleware on the routes/api.php file on the routes that needs authenticated user only like below

```
  Route::post('/comments', CommentsController@post')->middleware('auth:api');
```

Then let routes which do not need authenticated users to be like so

```
  Route::get('/comments', 'CommentsController@index);
```