# Laravel Passport Middleware "auth:api" Always Returns 401 with Valid Token

Tags: php, laravel, postman, laravel-passport

I am creating a Laravel API and want to secure it with Laravel Passport, however, it seems I can't get authenticated.

I began by securing my API routes using the Middleware `auth:api` inside my `RouteServiceProvider.php`

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api')
         ->middleware('auth:api')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

I also made sure to change the API driver in my `config/auth.php` to use `passport`

```
'api' => [
     'driver' => 'passport',
     'provider' => 'users',
     'hash' => false,
 ],
```

I've then generated token using the methods recommended in the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport#requesting-tokens). I did this inside of Postman.

[image: Postman Request for Bearer Token]

I then used the Bearer token in the request Headers, along with the `Accept` and `Content-Type` being set to `application/json` (I've seen a lot on this issue in which people said this should be done)

And the Route in my `api.php`

```
Route::prefix('auth')->name('auth.')->group(function() {

Route::get('/user', function() { return response()->json(['error' => false, 'message' => 'Hello World']); })->name('user');

});
```

However, when I send the request I received the same 401 error given by Laravel Foundations `Handler.php` (I've edited the response to fit my use case but that has no affect on my current issue)

```
"messsage": "Unauthenticated."
```

Returning with the following headers;

[image: Headers of Postman Request]

While doing my research [I found a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53736145/laravel-passport-always-returns-401-unauthenticated) which described what I was experiencing but it seemed that it has been abandoned and no answer was provided. Any ideas?

Comment: did you adjust your authentication guard named `api` to use passport?

Comment: Yeah sorry, forgot to mention that in the question. I'll add that in. It uses the passport driver

Comment: Show the headers for the request that is failing.

Comment: Had a similar situation with postman. Needed to adjust HTTP Authorisation. Followed this: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-passport-and-postman-gets-all-the-time-unauthorised?#reply=332616 worth a shot i think.

Comment: Hi. I hope this link https://medium.com/modulr/create-api-authentication-with-passport-of-laravel-5-6-1dc2d400a7f will help.

Comment: @user3532758 my .htaccess already had HTTP Authorisation

Comment: @DawudAbdulManan Thank you but I have already read that article and that method seems like just a workaround rather than a solution.