# Consuming API with JavaScript - Valid token - Unauthenticated

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-passport

So, I saw like 101% of the issues about this and did try each and every single one of them. I'm trying to get it running for like 3 days with no success. The person I work with on the project is doing the exact same thing and it's working for him.

I have set the routes,
I have`\Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,` in my **middlewareGroups->web**,

I am sending the headers with the requests,
I have `protected static $serialize = true;` in `EncryptCookies`,

Here's an example:

```
X-CSRF-TOKEN: 8Gr7XcRZDrfiFIwqaPyqVF1stXdIxv1tQ4Up6JUr X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest X-XSRF-TOKEN: eyJpdiI6ImU3RFRTRlNNd2hRc0J3bU9qb2l2UGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiaWJnd1wvWTdteW1Cd2w5Zll2SmYwdkplQ094R05HUzZPckM0NUNrdFB5alNpTDduWHkxczZWcU5maW9WS1VnRk9RZGZqdGJQM1FXR29JMFhDS2RyMTVBPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI4YmRmMWI1OWI4OTg1NTM0NmU2Mjk4ZjM0YmU2NjJkOTAwM2JlZDYxZDBkNTEzZDc3ZTdmOTk0NGYwZDBjMWQzIn0=
```

and it always says

> {"message":"Unauthenticated."}

I'm running Laravel latest version, on Homestead on Windows.
I would really appreciate a little help, I have tried everything and nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

The auth token you are looking for, is [mentioned here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript) . It will attach a cookie called `laravel_token` to the response, so it should work out of the box with axios. But again, depends on how you setup your axios, and if you are not using axios, then you need to manually set your the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` in your request header.  It seems that you are setting `X-XSRF-TOKEN`, which is not what Laravel uses to authenticate.

Credit: [Laravel 5.4 passport axios always returns Unauthenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42030727/laravel-5-4-passport-axios-always-returns-unauthenticated/42032593#42032593)

Comment: I do have this set up, I should have mentioned in my question. window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.Laravel.csrfToken,
  'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
};

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a middleware is returning `unauthenticated` while validating the access token.

If you're using a middleware to validate the access tokens on incoming requests, for example: `->middleware('auth:api');`, then on your javascript you should specify the access token as a `bearer` token in the authorization header of the request.

The access token should looks like: `'Bearer '+access_token`

Here is the complete explanation: [Protecting Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#protecting-routes)

Comment: I am using the middleware in the constructor, but since I'm only making requests from the front-end of the website, not a third-party one, I don't think I have to use Bearer token. That's why I'm using that's written in the Consuming your own API with JavaScript section.