# Laravel 5.3 Passport api routes are returning Unauthenticated error

Tags: laravel-5.3, postman, laravel-passport

I am new in Laravel Passport and I am able to get the the tokens from Laravel like below with Postman.

[image]

With this token, I tried to access my api route **user-details**

```
 Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth:api'],function(){
   Route::get('user-details','ApiController@getUsers');
 });
```

Here I am getting

```
{
"error": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

What is the issue actually ?

Comment: you can check it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39228194/passport-unauthenticated-laravel-5-3

Comment: Already checked this question, No hope.!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't mention this step, I am guessing you might have missed this step.

```
'api' => [
    'driver' => 'passport',
    'provider' => 'users',
    ],
```

Read the documentation fully.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport#client-credentials-grant-tokens. Hey, you are using client credentials grant token, its different from password grant etc.